# FETCH IE11: second fetch is not working in ie 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, fetch-api, polyfills

the first time fetch is called, everything works correctly. on the second call, I get false. It works correctly in Chrome. Polyfill fetch is connected.

The code below translates to ES5 before uploading it to the server.
*I have hidden some variables.*

```js
const url = `Fake url for example`;
function addData(data) {
            console.log("Affiche", data);
            const randomAffiche = data.data[getRandomInt(data.data)];
            const date = randomAffiche.PROPERTY_DATES_VALUE.split('-')[1];
            eventImgElem.src = randomAffiche.IMG;
            eventTitleElem.innerHTML = randomAffiche.NAME;
            eventTitleElem.href = randomAffiche.DETAIL_PAGE_URL;
            eventLink.href = randomAffiche.DETAIL_PAGE_URL;
            eventDate.innerHTML = getMonth(date);
            eventLink.innerHTML = randomAffiche.PROPERTY_VENUE_VALUE;
            whereToGoLink.href = '/kudago/';
        }

        function fetchData(city) {
            try {
                fetch(url + city) // This fetch is returned data = false. Why?
                    .then(data => {
                        data.json()
                            .then(data => {
                                console.log("fetchData", data);
                                addData(data);
                            })
                    })
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }

        }

        function getCity() {
            const url = "fake url for example";
            try {
                fetch(url) // This fetch is good
                    .then(data => {
                        data.json()
                            .then(data => {
                                console.log("getCity", data)
                                if (data.data) {
                                    fetchData(data.data.name); 
                                } else {
                                    console.log("Error getCity", data);
                                }
                            })

                    })

            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
        getCity();
```

[image][image]

[image: Chrome is ok]

Comment: are you expecting `city` as `path` or `query` parameter ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey I get the city from the first request. In the second query, I want to use this city.

Comment: yeah I can see that. I am just trying to ask if that makes a valid url when you concat city with the url. How do you expect the url to be formatted ? something like `url/city` ? or `url?city=anycity`

Comment: @GeorgeBailey initially the variable looks like this: ` const url = `/.../.../.../ajax.php?mode=class&c=...=getEvents&city=`;` + city

Comment: I am not sure but looks like an issue with passing parameters to the `url`. try with googling something like that

Comment: Try to print the URL in console to check whether it is proper or not. Try to directly paste in browser to see the result. It can help you to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT `console.log(url + city)` `// ../somePath=getEvents&city=Moscow`

Comment: For testing purpose, try to concatenate URL + city first and store it in a variable and pass the variable to fetch().

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Already tried, the error remained.

Comment: If you directly try to pass the URL with city to Fetch () does it work and give you the desired response? If you did not tested it then please try to test it to see the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method helped me https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

```
encodeURIComponent(url)
```

IE 11 did not understand the cyrillic alphabet.
this will help those who have Cyrillic in the request.